# Alertbox on a Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I try to have an alert box on my Fragment. My goal ist to logout a user. Before the user is logged out he hast to confirm it via the alert box.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val builder =AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    builder.setTitle("Ausloggen")
    builder.setMessage("Willst du dich wirklich ausloggen?")
    builder.setPositiveButton("Abmelden",
        { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int -> //Code zum Ausloggen })
            builder.setNegativeButton("zurück", { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int -> })
            builder.show()
        })



    RegistrateUser.getAuth()?.signOut()
    startActivity(Intent(activity,LoginActivity::class.java))
}
```

Thats the code so far but it doesnt work. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Any error? Does it compile? What happens if you click it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your `dialog.show` inside your positiveButton click, thats why it will never work. Change it like this:

```
val builder =AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
builder.setTitle("Ausloggen")
builder.setMessage("Willst du dich wirklich ausloggen?")
builder.setPositiveButton("Abmelden",
    { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int -> 
        /* your signout logic which I believe is this one: RegistrateUser.getAuth()?.signOut()*/
        
 })
        
    })
builder.setNegativeButton("zurück", { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int -> })
builder.show()
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Yes it works. i put the signout logic where it belongs. Thank you